# Post build script doesn't work on build server

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

We have some projects that use post-build events to copy files around the solution.  However, we are now upgrading to TFS 2018 (from 2012) and the events do not work.  The events use the SolutionName and SolutionDirectory variables in VS to build but those are undefined on the build server.  Is there a way I can get these to work without providing static paths and no functional changes to local builds?

Comment: Are you executing DEVENV.EXE to carry out the builds ? The post-build events in VS.net are instructions to DEVENV not build instructions as such.

Comment: @PhilipH I'm using the WPF build template in TFS2018.  The build process already tries to execute the script after the build.  Is it possible that i need to install VS on the build server as well?  I have the tools installed, just not the full IDE.

Comment: Sam - its a terminology thing; VS.net "Build Events" that you enter in the Project Properties in VS.net dont go into build scripts -they are just VS.net automation tools. If you need that same logic in your build environment you need to code them explicitly into your build script - either TFS or other.

Comment: @Sam Which version of VS did you use?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT VS 2017.  I defined the SolutionDir and SolutionName variables in the variable tab and so now the log doesn't show them as "undefined" but it still doesn't look like they are working correctly.  I've gotten around it by adding new Copy task in the build task.  Just wondering why this was necessary.  We are in a heavily regulated sector (Medical) so changing things like this is met with a lot of skepticism.

Comment: @Sam If you build your project manually in VS 2017 on your build agent server, is it working? Could you check the solution in this case to see whether it helps: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/65435/solutiondir-macro-at-build-event-gives-undefined-w.html

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I don't have VS installed on the build server - only the build tools.  Do I really need to install all 48G of VS for this?

Comment: @Sam Do your try the solution in the link I provide:? Try command `msbuild.exe path\to\solution.sln /t:ProjectName`. Also, you could only install the components of VS you need.

Comment: I think i'm going to stick with what I've got using other build tasks.  I'd prefer not to install VS for this.